# Does Twitter know which message have already been downloaded and how?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I was wondering how Twitter figure out if it should upload a tweet to a user or if it should not because the tweet has already been uploaded to the iOS client?

Is there an ID with each tweet?

I'm trying to find the best way to not send data twice to users.

Thank you.

Comment: Just keep track of what data you send to what users.

Comment: Isn't it way too heavy after a while if the server must remember everything? Currently the client tell the server what he has downloaded.

Comment: The server doesn't have to remember *everything*. For example, if a person has seen everything up to a certain timestamp, you can drop history for all events prior to that timestamp. You've then consolidated keeping track of thousands of things to a single data element.

Comment: timestamp seems the best but wont work for my situation, if user preferences changes then new data prior to the timestamp might be available.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter checks the content of the tweet you attempt to launch. If it's a duplicate of a previous one, it blocks it (seriously, what's the use of a duplicate message?). Find a way not to tweet twice the a tweet with the same text/link/image.

Comment: I was talking about tweet from other users that we download.

Comment: What does the goat have in common with the bike? Twitter blocks duplicate tweets received from the same user (regardless of the device he has logged in). This is the only thing you should keep in mind.

Comment: No I'm saying when you look for tweet sent by other people how does the server knows that a tweet was already downloaded by a user and thus dont need to receive it again.

Comment: Twitter's engine provides a notification response when launching a tweet to a user. After receiving the delivery confirmation, the server  "forgets" about this tweet. In case the confirmations is "false" (the user is offline, or whatever), the server will periodically try sending it until sent. It is API related, you don't have to bother was the tweet delivered or not. It will be for sure.